# Generating report in Oracle APEX with BI Publisher

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, bi-publisher

I'm trying to generate a report integrating BI Publisher with Oracle Apex. I've done successfuly the connection with the printing server with an HTTPS protocol. After that action I've generated a Report Query and straightaway, a Report Layout. When I generate the layout, APEX throws me an URL which I have to put in a page button. The problem goes in this part. When I click the button, my APEX application throws me the following error:

```
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEX.UNHANDLED_ERROR
ora_sqlcode: -29273
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failed
```

I've configured a Wallet in my database and I revised all the SSL certificates, but it fails too.
Summing up, everything goes well until I try to generate the report.
Thanks in advance.

I'm expecting to generate a report using BI Publisher in Oracle Apex.

Comment: Have you matched the wallet_path in the INTERNAL instance settings for APEX? APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.SET_PARAMETER('WALLET_PATH','xxx')